# How can I create a variable with the same type as a given function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a C++ function like

```
int f( const std::string &s, double d );
```

Now I'd like to create a variable which holds a pointer to `f`. This variable should have the correct type (`int (*)( const std::string &, double )` - but I don't want to write out that type explicitely. I'd like to deduce it from `f` so that I don't repeat the type signature. Eventually, I'd like to be able to write something along the lines of:

```
TypeOf<f>::Result x = f;
```

To achieve this, I tried to do something like this:

```
// Never implemented, only used to deduce the return type into something which can be typedef'ed
template <typename T> T deduceType( T fn ); 

template <typename T>
struct TypeOf {
    typedef T Result;
};

// ...
TypeOf<deduceType(f)>::Result x = f;
```

My hope was that maybe the return type of a function (`deduceType`, in this case) could be used as a template argument but alas - it seems you can't do that.

Does anybody know how to do this? I'm looking for a C++03 solution.

Comment: Could you give just one example when you really need typeof and there is no better solution without typeof?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++0x added [decltype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype) which does what you want (if I understood correctly).

Another option might be [Boost::Typeof](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/typeof.html) which is intended to provide the same functionality until decltype is supported in all compilers.

Comment: Ah, that's good to hear. Unfortunately, I'm trying to find a C++03 solution.

Comment: Ah, it's good to see that it's possible *somehow*, given that Boost can do it. ;-) It's a rather large library and I just need support for MSVC7 and newer and global functions.; I wonder how they did it.

Comment: And also, Boost takes care of the implementation differences for various compilers which means you would probably also have to do that if you intend your code to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your variable like this:

```
int (*FuncPtr)(const std::string& s, double d);
```

Here FuncPtr IS your variable. and you can use it like: `int result = FuncPtr(str, d);`, provided FuncPtr is not NULL. For that you could do:

```
int result = 0;
if (FuncPtr)
{
   result = FuncPtr(str, doubleValue);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. The whole point of my question is to avoid repeating the type signature when defining the variable. I'd like to deduce it from the given function which the variable should point to.

Comment: Isn't `auto` part of C++03? If it is wouldn't it solve your issue? Like `auto x = f`???

Comment: @ViteFalcon: `auto` exists in C++03, but it does something entirely different. :-}

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with the current standard, use `BOOST_TYPEOF` - ala:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>

struct foo
{
  int f( const std::string &s, double d ){ std::cout << "foo::f()" << std::endl; return 0;}
};

int main(void)
{
  BOOST_TYPEOF(&foo::f) x = &foo::f;

  foo f1;

  std::string s("he");

  (f1.*x)(s, 0.); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use typedef. You may repeat typedef name instead of the whole function signature.

In most cases typeof is not a good idea even if you can do it.

```
typedef int (*FuncType)( const std::string &s, double d );
```

Comment: The thing is - the function signature is implicitely given by the function `f` already. So the typedef actually repeats this.

Comment: "typedef actually repeats this" Not exactly. Actually the function must repeat the `typedef` (i.e. be the object of the appropriate type). This is the whole idea with types and objects - you define the object of some specific type and then you initialize it using some initializer or passing parameter (if the object is function argument). In this situation `typedef` should define the type (its name should give some hint about semantics) and the specific function is just object (one of many).

Comment: How would that work in practice? How would I define the function without repeating it's signature which I already gave in a typedef?